# Unable to verify ssl client authentication in Oracle database using jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, authentication, ssl, oracle19c

I have configured ssl for an oracle database. But I am unable to verify if the configuration is actually working.

Certifiate Creation steps:

```
orapki wallet create -wallet "/home/app/oracle/SSL0702" -pwd WalletPasswd123 -auto_login

orapki wallet add -wallet "/home/app/oracle/SSL0702" -dn "CN=SSL0702SRV" -keysize 1024 -self_signed -validity 365 -user_cert -trusted_cert -pwd WalletPasswd123

orapki wallet export -wallet "/home/app/oracle/SSL0702" -dn "CN=SSL0702SRV" -cert Server.crt -pwd WalletPasswd123
```

Done the same in the client side. Exported the server.crt to client side and client.crt  to the server side

```
orapki wallet add -wallet "/home/app/oracle/SSL0702" -user_cert -trusted_cert -cert Client.crt -pwd WalletPasswd123
```

Listener.ora

```
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = false
WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = FILE) (METHOD_DATA = (DIRECTORY = /home/app/oracle/SSLTRY0702)))
LISTENER = (DESCRIPTION_LIST = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DB-Oracle)(PORT = 1521))(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = DB-Oracle)(PORT = 2484))))
```

sqlnet(server side)

```
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = false
ADR_BASE = /home/app/oracle
WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = FILE)(METHOD_DATA =(DIRECTORY = /home/app/oracle/SSLTRY0702)))
```

sqlnet(client side)

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (BEQ,TCPS,NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE = (METHOD = FILE) (METHOD_DATA =(DIRECTORY = "D:\\certs\\SSLTRY0702")))
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = False
```

I have converted the .crt files created to jks keystore using the below commands.

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias ca -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 3650 -keystore cacert01.jks -storetype JKS -dname "CN=DemoSRVCA, OU=IT, O=My Company, L=My City, ST=My State, C=My Country" -storepass changeit -keypass changeit

keytool -import  -trustcacerts -keystore cacert01.jks -storepass changeit -file server_cert.crt -alias Server_04CER07022024
```

I am trying to connect to the database using DBVisualiser tool. I have set the net.ssl.trustStore, net.ssl.keyStore parameter to the respective directory. But I am able to connect to the database with just the truststore(when I change the directory throws error), but I want to establish client authentication.